# Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [hibernate_sequence]

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have simple question. I am using postgresql with spring, hibernate and jpa and postgres is used at backend. I am using strategy `GeneratedType.Idendity` and my database is already incrementing by 1 using internal sequence.

Now While running application I am getting error as:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [hibernate_sequence]
```

please note I am using sequences created form database. Not creating manually

Comment: You should post the code sample of your application, like how your entities look like etc.

Comment: If you are using sequences then the generation type is SEQUENCE not IDENTITY